# Firebug is breaking at a specific line in a specific file for no reason

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug

So I'm trying to debug this website.  I'm not new, and I use Firebug all the time.  I usually love it.  Today, I want to nuke it from space.

Firebug is breaking at line 238 in omniturescript.js.  It's just me.  This is not replicable for anyone else.  It's just my machine.  It's almost as if there is a config line somewhere that says, "Hey, if you get to like 238 in omniturescript.js, break. I don't care if there's a breakpoint or not.  Just break. No matter what."

Clearly I've somehow inadvertently done something that is making this happen.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Firebug to no avail. Clearing caches. You know, all the basic stuff. I'm out of ideas.  Maybe there's a firebug config file or history or something I need to delete somewhere?

I just can't make it NOT break at this line.  There are no errors.  I just arbitrarily decides to break at this specific line in this file, and only for me.

WHAT HAVE I DONE?

(thank you)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it!

Went to about:config in Firefox

Changed the config setting **extensions.firebug.breakOnErrors** to false.

Now it works.

(so odd!)